# Not echoing the last inserted row's HTML column?

Tags: php

In the following code, it should echo the last inserted row's column `HTML`; though instead it just gives me a bunch of errors.

These are the errors:

`Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/Admin/launcherNews.php on line 4`

`Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/Admin/launcherNews.php on line 6`

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/Admin/launcherNews.php on line 7`

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    include "../connection.php";
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `LauncherHTML`");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($fetch);
    $Code = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `LauncherHTML` WHERE ID='$num'");
    $gC = mysql_fetch_object($Code);
    echo $gC->HTML;
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's an error with the first query.  That's why num_rows is returning a boolean (false). Can you confirm you can connect to hte database?  Does that table exist?   And don't use mysql_* anymore.  Use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: The table exists, and I can confirm I can connect

Answer (score 0):

Probably $fetch = FALSE because

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `LauncherHTML`");
```

fails.

Therefore the first warning:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/Admin/launcherNews.php on line 4
```

says $fetch is a boolean instead of a resource.
The other warning and notice are following for the same reason.

You can find out the result of your query with:

```
echo mysql_error();
```

Furthermore the mysql extension is deprecated as of php 5.5.0. I strongly suggest you make use of PDO_MySQL or at least MYSQLi